# what does key size (64 bit) in DES means

Tags: cryptography, openssl, des

I im taking cryptography classes and learned that the key size of DES is 64 bits.
So 
if the key is array of Alphabetic char, and 1 char takes 8 bits 
then 
64/8 = 8 .
So the key can be only 8 char long maximum. 
Example :
aaaaaaaa or acacacac

But when i used openssl to encrypt data using DES it accepts keys more then 8 char long.

```
root@io:~# openssl enc -des -in data -out data.enc
enter des-cbc encryption password: aseaxsasceaceasxaeaxsaceac
Verifying - enter des-cbc encryption password:aseaxsasceaceasxaeaxsaceac
root@io:~# openssl enc -d -des -in data.enc -out data.plain
enter des-cbc decryption password:aseaxsasceaceasxaeaxsaceac
```

And it accepts even more long keys then i posted here.

1) So my question is what does key size (64 bit) in DES means what point im missing .
And
2)If key can be just 64 bit long really then how much time does it takes to crack a 64 bit key if plain text and cipher text is known

Comment: Hi, please check with Cryptography Stack Exchange for this question. If you can't find the answer there, please post your question there. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you need to read the manual for openssl. The password is not the key. The key is derived from the password.

Comment: seems like i dont have patience and got an answer from the irc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, just to get this out of the way: the key size of DES is not 64 bits in any meaningful sense; only 56 bits are actually used in the encryption or decryption (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard)). The other 8 bits are for parity (error checking). In practice, they are usually ignored.

---

The `openssl` utility's `enc` operation (or, simply, the [`enc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/enc) command itself) expects a passphrase, not a key (unless you use the `-K` option). The passphrase is turned into a key (of the appropriate length) using a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). This happens internally; you the user don't really control the process.

---

Breaking DES is actually pretty easy, due to its **56-bit** key length being short enough to brute-force search (trying every key until one works). Modern personal computers will still take months (possibly only weeks for the fastest) in a typical-case scenario. However, [dedicated hardware designed for the purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Custom_hardware_attack), or a distributed network of computers, can break a DES key in [under a day](http://www.sciengines.com/company/news-a-events/74-des-in-1-day.html?eab1dd0ce8f296f6302f76f8761818c0=0b59c5b91984fe01986ef3bbc6de9871). Bear in mind that those machines are now a few years old, and Moore's Law is extremely applicable to this kind of brute-force operation; what took tens of thousands of dollars and a day of work eight years ago would today take under a thousand dollars to build, or only a few hours per key.

Comment: The password mechanism is `EVP_BytesToKey` with a single iteration of a hash function. Brute-forcing the password would probably be easier (although a 64 bit salt makes rainbow table attacks infeasible).